# SendMessage(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam) difficulties

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to make a program click a button on another program; I decided to use the function:

```
SendMessage(hWndVariable, MsgVariable, wParamVariable, lParamVariable)
```

but there is an issue. The window with the window handle hWndVariable has 3 buttons. I initially planned to use the following parameters in the SendMessage function:

```
SendMessage(hWndVariable, BN_CLICK, 0, 0);
```

Question::   but since there are 3 buttons, how would the program know which one is being clicked? lol I am guessing that I am either missing something or doing something completely wrong.

Comment: What language are you using? (You've tagged three different ones.)

Comment: Do you mean [BN_CLICKED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825(v=vs.85).aspx), which is reasonably well documented?

Comment: @user3552287 As Alan noted, please don't use three different language tags on your question. You've done this with your other questions as well, and it makes helping you more difficult than it would be with one language tag.

Comment: You are doing it all wrong anyway. Use automation as you are intended to do.

Comment: I am using c++, sorry about that :P

Comment: No matter what language you're using, you should still use UI Automation to do this. `BN_CLICKED` is *not* a message, it is a notification. And if the button is in a dialog, you need to send this notification to the dialog, not the button. Things start getting complicated really quickly trying to do it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SendMessage(hWndVariable, BN_CLICK, 0, 0);

This is your problem right here. First, you're sending a nonexistent message (you meant `BN_CLICKED`). Second, you're not sending the message correctly.

As described in [answers to your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23173692/2245528), you need to get the button's ID. [You can do this using Spy++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23185894/2245528).

Then, per the [`BN_CLICKED` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825(v=vs.85).aspx), you can send your message like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14962217/2245528):

```
SendMessage(parentWindowhWnd, WM_COMMAND, (BN_CLICKED << 16) | BUTTONID, buttonhWnd);
```

Fill in the values appropriately - `parentWindowhWnd` is the HWND of the window containing the button, `BUTTONID` is the button's ID, and `buttonhWnd` is the HWND of the button itself.

Comment: Awesome. I know how to get the parentWidowhWnd with FindWindowEx() but how would I go about finding the button handle? I mean I used spy++ to get the window name and used that in FindWindowEX to find the handle, but I couldn't find the button's ID... what steps must I take to find the button's ID in spy++?

Comment: btw, why did you use WM_COMMAND where I thought BN_CLICKED should be?

Comment: You would find the button handle as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23173692/2245528) shows: `EnumChildWindows` on the parent window, then check each child window's ID via `GetWindowLong` with `GWL_ID` against the ID you get from Spy++. When you find a matching ID, there you go.

Comment: And I used `WM_COMMAND` because the `BN_CLICKED` docs say _The parent window of the button receives this notification code through the WM_COMMAND message._ Please look at the links I left in my post, I believe they answer your questions fairly neatly.

Comment: The thing is every time I run the program again, the child window has a different handle and ID, so If I get the ID from spy++, that ID will only be valid while the program is still running. If tomorrow I run it again, there will be a new ID and handle value... so how do I get around that issue?

Comment: The button ID should remain the same. The handle will not, which is why you `FindWindowEx` to get the parent window and `EnumChildWindows` to get the button.

Comment: thing is EnumChildWindows is used to look through each child window in the callback function, but what function can I use to find the button ID for the buttons inside the child windows? Is there any function you know of?

Comment: computerfreaker... do you know any way I can see all the controls a specific window has? I know that GetDlgCtrlID() can be used to get the Id of a control so If I knew what controls are there maybe I could work something out

Comment: @user3552287 Why not use Spy++ to get the button's ID, then `EnumChildWindows` to iterate through the parent window's controls, checking each control's ID against the one you got from Spy++?

Comment: thats the thing bro, I have been trying to use spy++ to get the button's ID but i cant seem to find out how to do it. I mean I click the "log" button and then pick the "finder tool" which seems to only click on windows. There is even a text next to the finder tool that says: "Drag the Finder Tool over a window to select, then release the mouse button."... window, not button... ahh im confused how to find a buttons info

Comment: Buttons are a type of window too, really. Almost every control is. (If it helps, creating buttons requires a call to `CreateWindowEx`.) You can drag the finder tool over a button the same as you can drag it over a window.

Answer (score 0):

[`BN_CLICKED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825.aspx) is a notification that the button sends to its parent window.  You are thinking of the [`BM_CLICK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775985.aspx) message instead, which you can send to a button window to simulate a click on it:

```
//SendMessage(hWndVariable, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
SendMessage(hWndVariable, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
```

In order for this to work, `hWndVariable` has to point to the specific button that you want to click on, not its parent window like you are currently doing.