# click button in java application from external .net c# exe

Tags: java, c#, windows, automation

I am trying to click on a button of a java application from an external c# windows console exe app.

I am using FindWindow to get the process, but then I don't know how to find the button handle using FindWindowEx or GetChildWindows. I suppose this is due to Java.

Is there a way to perform this ?

What alternative can be used to perform this task ?

Thanks

Pat

Comment: You can find a button with Spy++ https://stackoverflow.com/a/23173692/7357322

Comment: Unfortunately SPY++ only shows the main window, but not child windows for a java app

Comment: Use `inspect.exe` instead of spy++, see whether you can get the UI elements with it. No guarantee that those UI elements expose UI Automation patterns. -- In case you don't know, inspect.exe is usually located in `[Drive]:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\[Win Major version]\bin\[SDK version]\x64\inspect.exe`, which can be, e.g, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\inspect.exe` -- Related Docs: [Accessibility tools - Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects)

Comment: I do find a main window but unfortunately it says control has no filter. Does mean it's not possible ?

Comment: Using inspect, I am able to go to the level of the panel I am interested in, but unfortunately it does not go beyond that to the button control itself.

Comment: So it's probably a Java Swift UI. The container's coordinates may be enough if you can determine the Button's offset, because the Button should react to [mouse_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) calls (`MOUSE_LEFTDOWN` and `MOUSE_LEFTUP`) -- The notes in the Docs state that `SendInput()` should be used instead of `mouse_event`, but the latter works fine and it's still quite useful for quick tests.